# How can I tell R to use a specific reference level in a linear model?

Tags: r, unordered, linearmodels

I am trying to change the reference level for a linear model. R thinks my distance variable (entered as a character string) is "ordered" based on alphabetical order as follows: 10m, 15m, 20m(post), 20m(pre), 3m, 5m. But I'm really just analyzing these distances as discrete categories with respect to the dependent variable, and I don't need them in order. I just need to be able to tell R which one to use as a reference distance (and ideally be able to change it easily).

I can't use relevel to change the reference distance because it says it only works on "unordered" factors. So I used this code to tell R to unorder my "distance" factor: factor(distance, ordered = FALSE ), which seemed to run just fine, but then when I try to use relevel it once again says it only works on unordered factors.

This is all of the code:

```
factor(distance, ordered = FALSE)

C_data$distance <- relevel(C_data$distance, ref = "20m(pre)")

C_lm = lm(seedrate ~ distance, data = C_data)
```

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. E.g., this works: `distance <- ordered(c("10m", "15m", "20m(post)", "20m(pre)", "3m", "5m")); distance <- factor(distance,ordered=FALSE); relevel(distance, ref = "20m(pre)")`

Comment: Did you reassign the `distance` object - e.g. - `distance <- factor(distance, ordered=FALSE)` ?

Comment: I am new to R, so I have no idea how this works. If I modify a variable like "distance" to be unordered, then how do I get that modified variable back into the overall data set? No matter what I do to the variable, it never reflects these changes within the larger data set, so when I run a linear model it always does the exact same thing, no matter what other code I have run to modify "distance."

Comment: doesn't `mylm = lm(seedrate ~ factor(distance), data = C_data)` do the trick? check `summary(mylm)` to see which distance-category is omitted

Comment: Try `C_data$distance <- factor(C_data$distance, ordered = FALSE)` - I suspect you have an object called `distance` which is floating on it's own, as well as a column in `C_data` also called `distance`. See `ls()` to get a list of all the objects you have in your workspace.

Comment: The code: C_data$distance <- factor(C_data$distance, ordered = FALSE) doesn't do the trick because 10m is still first on the list, and R seems to be arbitrarily using whatever is first on the list as the reference level. The other code you mentioned above: distance <- factor(distance,ordered=FALSE); relevel(distance, ref = "20m(pre)") DOES reorder the levels and put 20m(pre) first, which is what I want, but that doesn't get that info back into the C_data set.

Comment: check how an ols-estimator subsumes estimates. you can calculate how estimates would change if one factor-level was omitted vs. each other (the factors are estimated against the benchmark which allows to change the benchmark). If you want to "trick" the system, you could add a "AAA" to the level that you want to omit.. `distance$ref[distance$ref=="20m"]<-"AAA_20m"`